# Windows Azure role recycles continuously with Microsoft-Windows-WAS Warnings

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, iis, azure, azure-web-roles

I know this is probably one of the most common Windows Azure deployment questions, but it's been troubling me for three to four days now and I can't seem to find the root of the cause. The cloud service deployment constantly restarts and recycles itself.

When I remote into the VM, I only see two Warnings (with Source "Microsoft-Windows-WAS") in the IIS Manager:

`[ID: 5048] The application '/' belonging to site '1' has an invalid AppPoolId 'DefaultAppPool' set.  Therefore, the application will be ignored.`

This is followed by:

`[ID: 5056] Site 1 was disabled because the root application defined for the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for information about why the root application is invalid.`

I've tried IntelliTrace but nothing helpful nor conclusive can be obtained in the short time that the web role is alive; under the *Sites* folder in IIS Manager there is nothing to be found. This is baffling me; I thought it was an SDK dependency mismatch so I went ahead to uninstall everything save for Windows Azure SDK 2.1, but the problem persists.

Debugging in the full compute emulator seems to return no issue, however.

Hope someone around here can help me out here... I'm desperate!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that I did not have anything in one my specified `VirtualDirectory`s, hence when it was packaged/published the physical folder was not created. As a result when the instance was initializing it could not find the physical folder for this `VirtualDirectory` mapping. Hence the error:

```
Exception:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: E:\sitesroot\1
```

My advice to anyone facing this issue is: always take a look at your Event Viewer and spend a couple of moments thinking of what could be the cause of the error... cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore those two warnings, they are common in all Azure deployments and won't have anything to do with your role or site.  There is a series of troubleshooting blog posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx which will walk you through exactly how to troubleshoot role startup failures.

Comment: Hi, I think I kind of forgot about Event Viewer somewhere down the road.. anyways under Microsoft\Windows Azure\Diagnostics\Runtime it says `Exception:System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: E:\sitesroot\1` .. why is it looking under folder `1`? (there is `0` and `2`; `0` just looks about right)

Comment: The \1 refers to the second site in your <sites> element in your .csdef file.